# How to access to paypal credentials from database?

Tags: laravel, paypal, credentials

I'm trying to find a optimal way to save and access my paypal credentials on laravel from my Database.

I know it is common to save this kind of data on the .env file or a config file, but I need the user to save his credentials instead of mine.

So what I really need is save the paypal credentials and give the opportunity to personalize their credentials and other data.

Comment: Do NOT save PayPal credentials. It violates PayPal's TOS and is a very, very bad idea for security reasons. PayPal provides APIs that allow you to generate reusable access tokens to do actions like making payments; do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this, but the most secure way in my opinion is to use a database. You can use Laravel's [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) to talk with your database. It is also a good idea to encrypt the user's PayPal credentials before storing them in your database.

Here is a sample of what I have done in the past to start my database. You will of course have to create the table in your database.

```html
<?php

namespace Application\UserCredentials;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Credentials extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'credentials';

    protected $fillable = [
        'clientID',
        'clientSecret',
        'user_id'
    ];
}
```

Here is an example of what I have used to add this to your database.

```html
<?php

use Credentials;

$userCredentials = Credentials->create([
            'clientID' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret
        ]);
```

This should get you started with what you can do with Eloquent in Laravel.